# How to achieve this rough borders and stippled illustration look?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustrator-effects

Looks like some post effect or maybe another technique. How to achieve this, any ideas?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15):

You could use the Wrinkle tool.  It's located in the Tool bar as shown below. Double click the Tool icon to change settings as required. These are the settings I chose.

[image]

Then use the tool as you would normally use the Brush tool, over the edges of a rectangle or shape, until it's rough enough.

[image]

The other answer given covers the addition of stippling/shading. So I won't repeat that.  However just to say that using the Wrinkle tool is a vector effect, rather than a raster filter.

Comment: That was my first answer that got some upvotes :D Feels great you mentioned it! BTW I like your approach more, since I also preferred vector output, but didn't know about this tool.

Answer (score 14):

Not sure about the exact effect, but you can use Illustrator's `Effect > Pixelate > Crystallize` to create a crystallized look for borders.

For those dotted 'gradients', you can either buy or create a stipple shading brush or you can find some [free to use brushes](https://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/freebies/8-free-stipple-shading-brushes-for-adobe-illustrator), like these:

[image]

[image]

<sub>(Above image credit: The same blog (spoongraphics) which I mentioned above)</sub>

That will give you similar look.

**Simple example:**

1. Create your two rectangles with some different colored borders.

[image]

2. Apply effect to both of them. Then go to `Object > Expand Appearance`.

[image]

3. Now you need to remove the unwanted border. For this use `Window > Image Trace` feature and then Expand it. Ungroup everything and delete unwanted shapes. You'll be left with this:

[image]

4. Then use those Stipple brushes. Select darker stroke colors. And use *Draw Inside* mode.

[image]